# Converting seconds since epoch, into full date for specific lines in a file

Tags: bash, date

I have the following file:

```
foo,1460844122
bar,abcd
bla,efjhi
foo,1464834121
baz,jklmn
```

I would like to read it line by line and only if "foo" appears as the first word, convert the second word (seconds since epoch) into full date and output *foo:full-date*.

How can I use Bash to accomplish this task?

Comment: What do you mean by "full date" exactly? The date as your `date` command prints it? ISO 8601?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
while IFS=, read -r k v; do
    if [[ $k == "foo" ]]; then
        printf '%s:%s\n' "$k" "$(date --date="@$v")"
    fi
done < /path/to/your/file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed `perl`:

```
perl -plE 's/^(foo),(\d+)/"$1:" . localtime($2)/e' < file
```

for your data it prints

```
foo:Sun Apr 17 00:02:02 2016
bar,abcd
bla,efjhi
foo:Thu Jun  2 04:22:01 2016
baz,jklmn
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F, '$1 == "foo" {printf "%s:%s\n", $1, strftime("%c", $2)}' infile
foo:Sat, Apr 16, 2016  6:02:02 PM
foo:Wed, Jun  1, 2016 10:22:01 PM
```

The first argument to the `strftime` function controls the date/time output format; `%c` is your locale's "appropriate" date and time representation. If we wanted something more sortable, we can use ISO 8601 date format and 24 hour time representation, separated by `T`:

```
$ awk -F, '$1 == "foo" {printf "%s:%s\n", $1, strftime("%FT%T", $2)}' infile
foo:2016-04-16T18:02:02
foo:2016-06-01T22:22:01
```